# How to prove the associativitiy condition in a set for a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

For this question, I am stuck on proving the associatitivty condition for the set to be a field. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me?

Is the set $\Bbb Q[
√
7] := {{a + b
√
7|a, b ∈ \Bbb Q}}$ with addition and multiplication
defined by
$(a + b
√
7) ⊕ (c + d
√
7) =(a + c) + (b + d)
√
7$ for all a, b, c, d ∈ Q,
$(a + b
√
7) ⊗ (c + d
√
7) =(ac + 7bd) + (ad + bc)
√
7$ for all a, b, c, d ∈ Q,
a field?

$[(a + b√7) ⊕ (c + d√7)]⊕(e+f√7)$

= $(a + b√7) ⊕ [(c + d√7)⊕(e+f√7)]$

= $(a + b√7) ⊕ [(c+e)+(d+f)√7]$

$[(a + b√7) ⊗ (c + d√7)]⊗(e+f√7)$

= $(a + b√7) ⊗[(c + d√7)⊗(e+f√7)]$

= $(a+b√7)⊗[(ce + 7df) + (cf + de)√7$

Comment: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt7)\subseteq\Bbb R$

Comment: Ok yes I got that, but how do we prove the associativity?

Comment: @dg123 You have associativity, commutativity, etc. **inherited for free** from $\;\Bbb R\;$ . I'm almost sure that's what Lord was trying to *hint* you...

Comment: Yes, but it's in the rational numbers, and how do we actually prove it though?

Comment: @dg123 What do you mean by "it's in the rational numbers"? The set $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 7]$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, and you're using the same multiplication rule from $\mathbb R$, so associativity of multiplication comes from restricting associativity of multiplication in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok, but is what I'm doing right so far? like do I need to go further?

Comment: So far so good. You just have to do a bit more to complete the proof. Just do it!

Comment: I'm just not sure how to go further though, so how do I go further?

Comment: Another common argument is that there is a bijection $\mathbb{Q}[t] / \langle t^2 - 7 \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ which preserves the ring operations.  Then associativity on the left hand side follows fairly easily from associativity in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$.